# Put in bold part of description in metatag Drupal module

Tags: html, drupal-7, metatag

I'm using **Metatag** module of Drupal 7. I want to put part of the description in **bold**.

For example, I have the following source code:

```
<meta name="description" content="My new content of web page" />
```

and I want to put "My new content" in bold.

Is it possible?

Comment: Should this description be displayed anywhere?

Comment: Yes, this appears when you click on right button of your mouse "see source code"

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

The [`meta`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)-[`description`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/document-metadata.html#meta-description) can only contain text:

> The value must be a free-form string that describes the page.

Even if you’d enter HTML elements, [they would just be displayed as text](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68500/17633).