# Any side effects of <p> tags in meta description

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, hubspot

I successfully imported meta description from a Wordpress blog to my new Hubspot COS by modifying WordPress export tool's php code , however with this workaround, HubSpot automatically adds paragraph tag (`<p>`) around the meta description.

[image]

Any idea if those tags can affect SEO or any aspect of my website?. 
Can i just ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

It's a paragraph tag which might consume some space.

You don't really need such codes in the header.

To reduce the clutter for the search engines you can just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid HTML, meta tag content type is : text

Answer (score 0):

As a `meta`-`description` can only have [text as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723493/1591669), your content is literally:

> <p>Our monthly installment […] shoots.</p>

This is [what consumers (like search engines) see](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68500/17633) and work with, e.g., what might be shown in snippets on SERPs.