# Special Characters in Meta-description

Tags: html, meta-tags

I would like to know if there is a reliable way to use symbols in meta-description like seen here

http://print24.com/ch-de/product/visitenkarten/

-> go to source-code and see within "meta description" the checkmarks used. Is this only possible with a supported font or would icons (glyphicon, fontawesome) also succeed.

The above example works in google but is there a reliable way to support bing and yahoo too?

Comment: Those are simple Unicode characters … and any font that has glyphs for them, can display them. (Trying to use your own icon fonts in that place however would not make sense – because Google & Co. will not use that font to display their search results.)

Answer (score 0):

A `meta`-`description` [can only contain text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723493/1591669).

In the example you mentioned, they use `✓`, which is just another text character (technically not different to `a`, `1` etc.). [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) defines all these characters. There are, for example, also [emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29) like  and .

For displaying these characters as intended, your users need to have fonts installed that contain/support them.

Comment: Obligatory [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). "*For displaying these characters as intended, your users need to have fonts installed that contain/support them.*": Also think about, for instance, google search results where these will be displayed/used; you don't always control the font.